# How to insert <br /> tags into a java String

Tags: java, regex, xhtml, jsf, facelets

I am trying to insert line break tags 
 into some text and displaying it on a web page.  The < and > signs are being translated into `&lt;` and `&gt;` and the tags are showing up as text on the web page.

The text looks like this when I select it from the database (I've output it to SYSOUT):

```
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime
service timestamps log datetime
service password-encryption
```

Then I run it through this little filter:

```
public DevConfigs getDevConfig() {

    String config = devConfig.getConfig();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".$", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(config);
    String newConfig = matcher.replaceAll("<br />");

    devConfig.setConfig(newConfig);
    return this.devConfig;
}
```

Here is the web page (it's a Seam application using facelets):

```
<rich:tab label="Config">
    hello<br />
    there<br />
    #{devConfig.config}
</rich:tab>
```

And the page source looks like this:

```
hello<br />
there<br />
&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;

version 12.&lt;br /&gt;
service timestamps debug datetim&lt;br /&gt;
service timestamps log datetim&lt;br /&gt;
service password-encryptio&lt;br /&gt;
&lt;br /&gt;
```

As you can see, my tag comes out as HTML characters and not as tags.  What do I need to do to insert line break tags at the end of each line of text??

TDR

Comment: You're not showing us the most critical code -- the code that outputs the string to the web page.  From what you've provided, the string definitely contains the "<" and ">" characters, not their HTML-encoded counterparts, so we now need to see the code that takes the `devConfig` object, retrieves the string, and outputs it.

Answer (score 7):

You need to disable the (default) HTML escaping of text. You can do that with `h:outputText` (or any RichFaces equivalent for that) with the `escape` attribute set to `false`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.property}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: This was originally inside an h:outputText tag, but I didn't know about the escape attribute.  I'm going to test this one out.  I ended up putting a <pre> tag around the output text.  Not to "hi tech", but it did work in the end.

Comment: I forgot to say that I took out all the regexp matching and replacing and just displayed the code as is from the database within a <pre> tag.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said before, its all about the view. You can't do anything just in the controller/model or java String. No magic escaping or combination can make the `<br>` get to the generated HTML unharmed. You have to find the required attribute change in your JSP.

In Struts is the **"filter"** one, put it false to avoid the escaping of your HTML:

Java

```
String text = "This line will <br> break";
```

JSP

```
<bean:write name="object" property="attribute" filter="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't write that much Java, especially nothing related to this, but I'm wondering, 
can this

```
<rich:tab label="Config">
    hello<br />
    there<br />
    #{devConfig.config}
</rich:tab>
```

not be written as this

```
<rich:tab label="Config">
    <![CDATA[
    hello<br />
    there<br />
    ]]>
    #{devConfig.config}
</rich:tab>
```

or simply:

```
<rich:tab label="Config">
    <![CDATA[
    hello
    there
    ]]>
    #{devConfig.config}
</rich:tab>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand your question completely. But isn't it possible to replace simply the `\n` with `<br />`?

```
public DevConfigs getDevConfig() {

    String config = devConfig.getConfig();
    String newConfig = config.replace("\n", "<br />");
    devConfig.setConfig(newConfig);
    return this.devConfig;
}
```

I entered your text in [this regex tester](http://www.regextester.com/). This works fine, but if I choose `Preg` by `Dialect`... He replaces with `&lt;br /&gt;`. Only with Javascript dialect it goes correct.
So maybe that is the same problem.

Oh. When you use `.$` for your regex, you remove the last char from the line (when replacing).